# Bootstrap CSS fixed height for div on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div with a fixed height.

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="height:250px;">
<img src="example.png" />
</div>
```

When I resize the screen to mobile, my div width is responive and shrinks but the height still keeps the same.

It's quite hard to formulate my question but is there anyway to use a fixed height but make it responsive ?

Comment: Set the max-height. `style="max-height: 250;"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add @media query to your css file to override the original one. Something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    myNewDivHeight{
        height:250px;
    }
}
```

Add this class to your div like:

```
class="col-md-12 myNewDivHeight"
```

When the screen res. is over 1024px this will work. When you shrink it will not work, so bootstraps responsive will trigger. Or you can add new media queries for other resolutions.

Comment: This should do the trick and easier to maintain if you need to change anything.

Comment: To make it complete : The original Bootstrap 3 ships with break points at 0px (xs), 768px (sm), 992px (md) and 1200px (lg).

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
<style>    
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
   #d1{
    height:250px;
      }
}      

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#d1{
    height:150px;
   }
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #d1{
        height:100px;
       }
}
<style>
```

and add Id to your div for example id="d1"

```
<div id="d1" class="col-md-12" style="height:250px;">
<img src="example.png" />
</div>
```

Also in bootstrap you can add class="img-responsive" to make your image responsive
like this :

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="example.png" />
```